# Unable to attach a live event to anchor within div in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, tags, tagging

I'm trying to use a simple modification for XOXCO's tagging input jquery plugin that allows you to limit the number of tags entered.

Everything is working correctly except for this part

```
$('.tag a').live('click', function () {
  if ($('.tag').length == 4) {
    $('#MainContent_postcontrol_step2_txtKeywords_tag').attr('disabled','false').show();
    $('#MainContent_postcontrol_step2_txtKeywords_tag').focus(); 
    $('.warning').remove();
  } 
});
```

No matter what I do, the click event is never assigned to a .tag's anchor. If I change it to simply .tag, the event fires when clicking on the div itself. Am I doing this part wrong?

EDIT:
Here is the plugin im using: http://xoxco.com/clickable/jquery-tags-input

And the modification: http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/mJdvu/1/

Comment: Can you include a link to the plugin you're using, please? And also perhaps a jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Just an FYI, `if ($('.tag').length = 4) {` is using an assignment operator, when it should be using an equality operator `==` or `===`

Comment: I edited the post with some more info. Someone pointed out that the = sign was being used instead of ==. This was my typo but the problem still remains. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like (= sign typo aside) that

```
$('#tags_tag').attr('disabled','false').show();
```

needs to be

```
$('#tags_tag').show()[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
```

in the fiddle

Comment: I see what you mean, but unfortunately the code doesn't even get that far. When I debug, the "live" event handler is never attached so it never fires. If only I could figure out why it won't add the event!